Can I ask for asylum as a 17-year-old in a UK airport?
I'm just asking this question for knowledge. If I want to ask for asylum in a UK airport as a 17-year-old can I ask? If I convince them that I have problems, what will happen next?
And what will happen if they don't believe me? Will they let me in?
What if they don't believe me, and I'm refused, will they forcefully remove me?
Give me more details about what will happen after I get my refugee status and everything please.

Can you please explain a little about the background behind your increasingly unusual questions? What is your end goal, where are your parents, why are you travelling alone and how did you get a child visitor visa to the UK?

I'm alone and my relatives did all thing for me. Now i have nowhere to go.

@JasbirMalik Nowhere to go and alone isn’t a valid reason to claim asylum, even as a 17yo child. Spending what must have been quite a lot of money on all those flights recently doesn’t sound like it was a good idea in those circumstances.

@JasbirMalik I'm sad and worried to hear that.  Do you have relatives or friends in India or the UK? Where are you living now? Is there a reason you cannot stay there?

Cautionary note: take a look at the reality of refugees in the UK https://www.refugeecouncil.org.uk/information/refugee-asylum-facts/top-10-facts-about-refugees-and-people-seeking-asylum/ . It is NOT a fun process: Even if you eventually are granted asylum you may end up in detention and/or without work permit for many years.

What if they rejected my asylum

@JasbirMalik What happens if they reject an asylum claim is set out in the document linked in the answer to your question. Ask a new question if that document does not provide the information you are looking for.

You can always ask for asylum. At age 17 you are considered a child.
After you make the claim you will be placed in care by the government.
Here is a page about the process of claiming asylum as a minor, whether accompanied or unaccompanied.
Here is a document laying out the process that happens after you claim asylum.. It's very detailed. Google will give you lots of other pages.
Asylum is for people who face persecution in their home country. Your life or freedom have to be at risk. If that's not the case your asylum claim will be denied very quickly and you will be sent home.
You will be given a number of interviews to check the truth of what you claim as the danger you are in. If you are not believed then you will be sent back to the country you came from, and will almost certainly never be allowed to visit the UK again. Certain countries are designated "safe" countries, which means that if you are coming from (or can get to) one of those countries you will not be accepted as a refugee. India is about to be added to that list, and even before it is you will face additional difficulties in convincing authorities that you are being persecuted there.
I strongly recommend that you do not attempt to claim asylum unless you are actually in danger and have nowhere else to go.

(+1) See also UK to add India to list of safe countries of origin for asylum seekers

Asylum is for people who are persecuted in their own country, and do not benefit from the protection of their own country (most often, either because it’s the state actually persecuting them, or because the state “sides with” those persecuting).
“Having nowhere to go” is not a valid reason for claiming asylum (and even “having nowhere to go” does not quite seem to match up with being able to pay for tickets to the UK, Turkey, France, and Mexico, looking at your previous questions).
Now, this does not prevent you from claiming asylum, but there is no guarantee it will be granted, and in your case, I don’t think there is any reason for you to be granted asylum (at least you haven’t given us any valid reason for that).
Being granted asylum is a long and complex process, and while in many cases you will be allowed to stay while they process your claim, it’s not necessarily a walk in the park, especially in the UK. They could put you on a barge, or they could (maybe) send you to Rwanda while your application is processed. During that time you may be restricted in your movements (not allowed to leave your assigned accommodation).
If your only argument is “I have nowhere to go” then expect your application to be rejected swiftly. In that case you will be returned to your home country, and should not expect to be able to enter the UK (and probably most other “rich” countries) for a very very long while. Of course you could make up whatever arguments and delay the process, but in the meantime it’s not like you can move and work and live freely.
Note also that since it’s so simple to claim, and the process may drag on for ages before asylum is either granted or denied, many countries try to make sure people who are likely to claim can’t even set foot on their territory (hence the introduction of airport transit visas for many countries).
The fact that you were previously granted a visa for the UK (though if I understand things correctly that went awry) means you declared to be in a situation which did not match those for asylum (otherwise they would probably not have granted one). This further reduces your chances of being granted asylum and increases the possibility of a prompt rejection.

(+1) Worth noting data on the high decision/rejection ratio for asylum applicants from India in 2023 - 1,519 rejections out of 1,661 decisions made

I just asked for knowledge.
